# Couldn't find 'project.json' in current directory on dotnet build

Tags: asp.net-core

i have a visual studio asp.net core v1.1 solution and want to build it with the 'developer command prompt for VS 2017'. Therefore i am using the following commands:

- cd (path\rootfolder of the VS Project)
- dotnet build

The result is always: **Couldn't find 'project.json' in current directory**

My **dotnet --info** result is:

- .NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-preview2-1-003177)

The Project has no project.json file due its usage of asp.net core v1.1. So all projects within the Solution have their own *.csproj files.

Does anyone have an Idea what could possibly go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have outdated tools. To build the new *.csproj structure, you need the latest tools installed. Since VS 2017 comes already with these tools preinstalled, I suspect that you have the older tools installed with a different architecture.

For example you maybe have x64 version of `1.0.0-preview2-1-003177` and preview4 in x86. Check the respective folders in `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk` (for x64) and `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk` (for x86) the uninstall the old one (Control Panel > Programs and Features)

Comment: As you said, i had two installations of the SDK, one in x64 and one x86. As soon as i uninstalled the old one in the x86 everything worked perfectly. Thanks for you help!

Comment: and on linux, where are the linux tools that work with .csproj-only projects?

Comment: I'm having this issue on Visual Studio online when trying to build and publish. Is it possible Microsoft have not updated the tooling on VS online? Or is there a way to choose which version it runs? I am using the .NET Core "Preview" task in my build steps. I have also tried with the standard Build along with changing the version to VS 2017 but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Now DotNetCore Projects Packages are included in  **<*projectName*>.csproj** File

[image]