# .NET Core 2 installed but not active

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

Im trying to install .Net Core 2. After running the installer i get the following message.

> The following were installed at C:\Program Files\dotnet
>
> - .NET Core SDK 2.1.4
> - .NET Core Runtime 2.0.5
> - Runtime Package Store

I reboot the computer and run in the cmd
dotnet --version
and get the response: 1.0.4

Ive checked the program folder and i do indeed find C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4

When i start VS 2017 i can not choose .Net Core 2. I can only choose Core 1 projects. I have tried reinstalling several times and i have restarted the computer several times.

I use VS2017 v 15.4.1

When checking folders i find this on my harddrive:

***C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk***

- 1.0.0-preview2-003131
- 2.0.2
- 2.1.4
- NuGetFallbackFolder

***C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk***

- 1.0.0-preview2-003131
- 1.0.0-preview2-00315
- 1.0.4

This is whats installed on my computer.

[image]

Comment: Where are you typing `dotnet --version`? Inside a project? Or a subfolder where it (or its parent) have a `global.json`? The global.json will override the current version for all folders below it. With the global.json you can specify a specific dotnet version for one folder and its subfolders. see [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json)

Comment: Also please make sure if you have x64 or x86 version and if both are updated. ideally you'd install one of these and only have either x64 or x86 installed. Its possible that you have both installed and only the first one in %PATH% environment variable is used and its the one not updated yet. May happen when you install it manually. Be aware that VS2017 installer will install its own dotnet runtime (which is x64 iirc) when you enable .net core in the installer

Comment: Also see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43045670/couldnt-find-project-json-in-current-directory-on-dotnet-build/43046024#43046024) on a similar  but older answers

Comment: Im typing it in the root c: And i get version 1.0.4
Im going to follow the rest of your tips now.

Comment: Ive edited OP and added a list of whats installed on my computer.

Comment: Ive updated OP again with the folders in the path you told me to check.

Comment: Either uninstall all x86 packages or install the LATEST version of both. Which one is used in CMD depends in which folder is first in the %PATH% environment variable